# How can i get the index of my current OnClick Row?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tablelayout

Basically i've been trying to get the index number of the row i click on, it's a code generated Table so i can't put the Id in the Xml, and i'm not really sure Where to put the SetTag that i've seen in some questions. Maybe there's an easier way. 
(the OnClick function is working with a TextView inside every TableRow of the TableLayout i created)
This is the code that's trying to do that:

```
View.OnClickListener myAddHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) v.getParent();
        int index=mTableLayout.indexOfChild(row);
        addedcode = data[index].productCode;
        addedcant = data[index].invoiceNumber;
        Intent switchIntent = new Intent(AddManager.this,NavManager.class);
        startActivity(switchIntent);
    }
};
```

And this is the code that generates the Table:

```
public void loadData(InvoiceData[] data) {
        int leftRowMargin=0;
        int topRowMargin=0;
        int rightRowMargin=0;
        int bottomRowMargin = 0;
        int textSize = 0, smallTextSize =0, mediumTextSize = 0;

        textSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size_verysmall);
        smallTextSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size_small);
        mediumTextSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size_medium);

        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        int rows = data.length;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Productos (" + String.valueOf(rows) + ")");
        TextView textSpacer = null;

        mTableLayout.removeAllViews();

        // -1 means heading row
        for(int i = -1; i < rows; i ++) {
            InvoiceData row = null;
            if (i > -1)
                row = data[i];
            else {
                textSpacer = new TextView(this);
                textSpacer.setText("");

            }
            // data columns
            final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

            tv.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);
            if (i == -1) {
                tv.setText("Cant");
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
                tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
            } else {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(row.invoiceNumber));
                tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
            }

            final TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
            if (i == -1) {
                tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
            } else {
                tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
            }

            tv2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT
            );

            tv2.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);
            if (i == -1) {
                tv2.setText("Agregar");
                tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
            }else {
                tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
                tv2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,0,R.drawable.cart);
                tv2.setOnClickListener(myAddHandler);
            }

            final LinearLayout layCustomer = new LinearLayout(this);
            layCustomer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layCustomer.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
            layCustomer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));

            final TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
            if (i == -1) {
                tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                tv3.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 5);
                tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
            } else {
                tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                tv3.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 5);
                tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
            }

            tv3.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);


            if (i == -1) {
                tv3.setText("Productos");
                tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
            } else {
                tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
                tv3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
                tv3.setText(row.productName);
            }
            layCustomer.addView(tv3);


            if (i > -1) {
                final TextView tv3b = new TextView(this);
                tv3b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tv3b.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                tv3b.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
                tv3b.setPadding(5, 1, 0, 5);
                tv3b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#aaaaaa"));
                tv3b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
                tv3b.setText(row.productCode);
                layCustomer.addView(tv3b);
            }

            final LinearLayout layAmounts = new LinearLayout(this);
            layAmounts.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layAmounts.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            layAmounts.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
            layAmounts.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));



            final TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
            if (i == -1) {
                tv4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                tv4.setPadding(5, 5, 1, 5);
                layAmounts.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
            } else {
                tv4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv4.setPadding(5, 0, 1, 5);
                layAmounts.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            }

            tv4.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

            if (i == -1) {
                tv4.setText("Precio");
                tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
                tv4.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
            } else {
                tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                tv4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                tv4.setText(row.precio);
                tv4.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
            }

            layAmounts.addView(tv4);

            if (i > -1) {
                final TextView tv4b = new TextView(this);
                tv4b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tv4b.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                tv4b.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
                tv4b.setPadding(2, 2, 1, 5);
                tv4b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00afff"));
                tv4b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            }


            // add table row
            final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            trParams.setMargins(leftRowMargin, topRowMargin, rightRowMargin, bottomRowMargin);
            tr.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            tr.setLayoutParams(trParams);

            int p=0;
            tr.setTag(p);
            tr.addView(tv);
            tr.addView(layCustomer);
            tr.addView(layAmounts);
            tr.addView(tv2);
            p++;

         mTableLayout.addView(tr, trParams);

            if (i > -1) {

                final TableRow trSep = new TableRow(this);
                TableLayout.LayoutParams trParamsSep = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                trParamsSep.setMargins(leftRowMargin, topRowMargin, rightRowMargin, bottomRowMargin);

                trSep.setLayoutParams(trParamsSep);
                TextView tvSep = new TextView(this);
                TableRow.LayoutParams tvSepLay = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                tvSepLay.span = 4;
                tvSep.setLayoutParams(tvSepLay);
                tvSep.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9d9d9"));
                tvSep.setHeight(1);

                trSep.addView(tvSep);
                mTableLayout.addView(trSep, trParamsSep);
            }


        }
    }
```

The Data that you keep seeing it's an array with five elements: id, invoicenumber, productname, productcode and price. I really need the help i've been stuck here for two days now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View v` parameter passed to the handler's `onClick()` method is the view that was clicked. You can use this fact, combined with `setTag()` and `getTag()` to store some extra information.

Inside `loadData()`, where you assign the click listener:

> ```
> tv2.setOnClickListener(myAddHandler);
> ```

you can set the tag of `tv2` to have your index:

```
tv2.setTag(i);
tv2.setOnClickListener(myAddHandler);
```

Now, inside your click listener, you can retrieve the index with `getTag()`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int index = (int) v.getTag();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I love you so much, thanks, as soon as i can i'll give you the answer